# Is what makes a proposition true only determined by its referent?

Tags: realism, propositions

I was wondering if it is *trivial* that when the content of a belief can be given or "[determined](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/idealism)" by mind independent reality, the belief is "about" mind independent reality.

I **think** that the content of a belief can be determined by something other than what it is about.

e.g. I believe that the earth orbits the sun because of the history of science, but the history of science is not the sun's orbit.

---

But:

- Is what makes a proposition true only determined by its referent?
- If so, does that mean the propositional content is only determined by the referent?

---

But I suppose that a proposition cannot be reduced to what makes it true...

Comment: Answers to the last two questions depend on one's theory of meaning: yes under Millianism, no under descriptivism of Frege-Russell. But I am not quite sure what the preceding paragraphs are getting at: are you asking about the difference between a reason for belief and its content,  between sense and reference, or...? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense_and_reference

Comment: i'm not sure that i can ask any clearer than i have. i'm asking whether being "determined by reality" trivially means being "about reality"

Comment: yeah i think i'm a little confused. i wasn't sure if i should start another thread, it made more sense in the context of another

Comment: I think even Millianists would admit that "determined by reality" does not necessarily mean "about reality". On a realistic position hallucinations and optical illusions are determined by reality, but they are not about it.

Comment: @Conifold my apologies i must have misunderstood who i was arguing about this with, on another thread

Comment: i think i was reading something into the back and forth which was not there > does the rejection of "epistemological idealism" trivially entail we know "of" something real? >> epistemological realism plainly implies ontological realism by default

Answer (score 1):

There are three layers not to be confused:

1. The *truth value* of a proposition is defined/determinable by (the properties of) its referent.
2. The *content* of a proposition is determined by some reality (perceptions, mood, thoughts, structure of objects,...) obviously, but it could be false or sheer nonsense.
3. Calling a proposition *knowledge* does mean endorsing its truth and implies that the content corresponds to the actual properties of the referent of this proposition.

Therefore, if a proposition is knowledge and its content is mind-independent (realism), it also has to have a mind-independent referent, as the content is some kind of definite assumption about something. It is about its referent and implies its existance. Otherwise the truth value would be indeterminable.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "its content is mind independent" there seems to be some disagreement as to my [implicit] question in the 1st paragraph: do you endorse it?

Comment: I'm not a realist, nope. But the basic assumption of realists is that we have a way to perceive the world exactly as it is, that means *as it exists mind-independently*. E.g. scientific realists that claim that our measurements and theories are able to describe the world *at least approximatly* as it actually is, not only as we as humans are able to make sense out of what we get out of it.

Comment: i'm not asking if you're a realist, but whether you mean "content is mind independent" to mean "determined by mind independent reality". i suppose you do, but i *thought* Conifold was claiming that obviously mistaken

Comment: I do not. As for propositions, I do not care about what determined them, wether pure thought, remembrence or something mind-independent. What I do care about is their referent and what calling them knowledge implies about it.

Comment: confusing, sorry

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN: In my wording, determining is *by cause*, that means making the thing the way it particularly is. There can be I know not what "entities" determining the content in this sense and it is 100% independent from that how the content *defines* the referent and of what nature it is. I can determine only by arbitrarily *thinking* the content of a proposition about something that has totally mind-independent existance. The determining of the content is definately *not* by mind-independent reality there. But the content, in sense of truth value, predicate and referent, ontologically is.

Comment: i'm not sure that the answer explicitly answers the question ? not that i'm not grateful for your concerned attention tho...

Comment: i downvoted because while it would be helpful to someone thinking about the meaning of "truth value" etc., you seem to fail to clarify any term in the question, or offer a reason for an answer to it. perhaps the fault of the question, but it *seems* you've assumed a mistake in it, and not demonstrated that mistake was made. which is entirely irrelevant to a question and answer site IMHO

Comment: fun demonstration that if A then not A is problematic. but yeah

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33818/discussion-between-mathemetician-and-philip-klocking).